# fo:block-container in fo:table-cell AntennaHouse

Tags: xsl-fo, antenna-house

I have a situation where I need to have an fo:block-container with multiple columns (column-count="4") inside an fo:table-cell
The fo:block-container contains a few  elements when I have 2 or three fo:blocks within the container everything works fine and the content is displayed properly within the table cell. When I have many fo:blocks in the fo-container the content of the fo:block-container pops out of the table cell and displays on the following page.
How can I ensure that the block-container with its content displays within the relevant fo:table-cell?
Actually it seems that the whole containing table-row is getting pushed to the second page although there is a lot of space to have that table-row on the same page with the previous row.
I should also add if I have fo:block-container column-count="1" it works properly when the count is > 1 the weird positioning happens

Comment: Do your table cells have borders so that you can see their extent?  Are you using any `keep-together`, `keep-with-next`, or `keep-with-previous` properties?  Showing some actual markup could make things clearer for us.

Comment: While testing I did add the borders manually to see where the content is being displayed exactly. I had version 6.2 installed further testing showed that it becomes buggy once there are an X amount of blocks (about 45 blocks)  in the fo:container and having column count>1 . The upgraded to a newer version and the issue is resolved. It seems to be a bug with the version I am using.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the bug is relevant to the version of AntennaHouse I am using. An upgrade to a newer release did resolve the issue.